Why the graph doesn't display the missing value even though values in data file are not missing?
i'm estimating a GARCH model , modeling the volatility in Bitcoin price and expected inflation, the graph is log diff of expected inflation proxy "market yield on treasury securities "
Thank you for your help
Edit: it turned out because i had small values and when taking the log , the log transormation reduced variables to 0 or missing value , how can i remedy

